# Is Cycles capable of generating a proper ambient-occlusion render pass?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, render-passes, ambient-occlusion

I really hope I'm doing something wrong: the ambient occlusion, in my knowledge, should be a calculation that's more related to geometry and light direction and directional shadows.
I'm attaching two images of the same scene.

This is what a typical AO pass, calculated with other 3D applications, looks like:

[image]

This is what Cycles generates when AO pass is activated:

[image]

First problem, I can't consider the latter an AO pass, that's something else. Actually, I noticed that this happens for interior renderings. For geometry that's not enclosed, the AO looks just fine.

Second: although I activated the de-noising for this rendering, the AO pass remains unaffected.

I'm not listing any specific settings I used, since this happens with just the default Cycles' setting and the AO pass checked. Right now I just need to clear out this doubt: have I missed some parameters or is Cycles just doing AO wrong, for interior scenes?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome. You might need to check and share your settings, because that second image does not look like an ambient occlusion pass, looks more like a beauty pass with ambient occlusion

Comment: Hi Emir, I agree it desn't look like an AO, that's the point of my whole question, but that's what Blender compositor visualizes when I directly connect AO from the "Render layers" node, to an Output node. I definitely fear that's what Cycles considers AO.
I'll post more information if needed, but let's see if someone is already aware of this as an issue.

Thanks!

Comment: "*This is what a typical AO pass, calculated with other 3D applications, looks like*" This is not real ambient occlusion, that looks like SSAO, Screen-Space Ambient Occlusion, which is an approximation for  real time rendering. Cycles doesn't produce this because it is a raytracer, at least not without some non-trivial node trickery. The second image is probably a lot close to real AO even though it is not what you want

Comment: Yes exactly, that's more like a dirt shader applied globally, and that's what I was looking for from Cycles. I believe it's possible doing that by adding an AO node to each shader in the scene, but I don't think that's reasonable.
So, if there's no practical way to obtain a SSAO or global "dirt" pass with Cycles, that dashes my hopes. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You should really check your settings. This is the AO Pass from one of my Blender renders https://imgur.com/a/rc6BuEA and i did not add AO node to them. If thats what you are looking for, then something is not right with your AO Settings

Comment: Reading your post again, i see that you mean complete inside scene. For that, go to Render Settings > Fast GI aproximation and reduce the AO Distance. Hope that helps

Comment: Emir, you gave me the correct answer: the default settings for the AO assign a very long distance, so, for enclosed spaces, it forces the calculation for objects that are beyond the walls of a room. Setting it to about 25 cm or 10 in is enough to produce the wanted result. Also, the noise problem is gone as well. Thanks a lot for brilliantly finding the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future Reference.

You can change AO distance inside Fast GI Aproximation.
Render Settings > Light Path > Fast GI Aproximation > AO Distance

[image]